RENEGOTIATING при выполнении команды RCPT TO:
У меня возникли сложности при отправке письма на свою электронную почту от почтового домена арендованного хостинга посредством PHPMailer. Чтобы разобраться что идет не так я решил подключиться к почтовому серверу вручную через терминал.
Чтобы подключиться к серверу использую команду
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect mail.aniproject.ru:587

Далее получаю большой большой вывод
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G4
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.hosting.reg.ru
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.hosting.reg.ru
   i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G4
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jan 23 14:29:50 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Feb 23 14:29:49 2025 GMT
 1 s:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G4
   i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Oct 12 03:49:43 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Oct 12 00:00:00 2027 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = *.hosting.reg.ru
issuer=C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G4
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4091 bytes and written 479 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: A656836A8E31B37D23D076B36362C521041E5BC6E915F71CF6013E68EF0FAB58
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 0B3B153F158A40F062514BD9B5D08817EECE55D6BDEB298F060724B4B79C942230D18AFECAF145A1779A085B993DE4B0
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1714261109
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
250 HELP

С командами EHLO и MAIL FROM проблем не возникает
EHLO mail.aniproject.ru
250-server109.hosting.reg.ru Hello mail.aniproject.ru [85.26.176.81]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-PIPECONNECT
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250 HELP
MAIL FROM: admin@aniproject.ru
250 OK

Проблема появляется когда я использую команду RCPT TO: reijiakkerman@gmail.com, вот ее вывод
RENEGOTIATING
depth=2 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G4
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.hosting.reg.ru
verify return:1

Как я понял из полученного вывода и долгого нагугливания у меня происходит повторная верификация SSL сертификата. Однако после нее я так и не получаю от сервера разрешения на ввод данных самого письма
Например вот что происходит когда я пытаюсь использовать после RCPT TO команду DATA
503 valid RCPT command must precede DATA

Не помню где видел и про SMTP ли это было, но мне кажется что здесь отсутсвует этап авторизации. В общем прошу почетных гуру программирования помочь с возникшей задачей)

Где-то между EHLO и MAIL FROM нужно залогиниться командой AUTH PLAIN
